# Unexpected results using rvideo RVidoe::Inspector

Tags: ruby, windows

Hi I'm trying to use the gem rvideo to transcode video files and am having results that don't match what I expect. I've downloaded the ffmpeg files from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, installed the rvideo gem.

I found that without specifying the ffmpeg_binary that it wouldn't work and gave an error.
I've several problems one being the output when I enter

```
require 'rvideo'

video = RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => "D:/The Vault/josh ruby/video transcoding/test1.mp4", :ffmpeg_binary => "C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe")
```

When I enter the above command I see a whole mess of an output which looks like build date, configuration options, etc(included at bottom of post)

but where I've seen on the documentation that you can enter commands like.

- video.fps
- video.resolution

They only return nil for me.

Can you not use rvideo on windows?

Output from top:

```
=> #<RVideo::Inspector:0x213ba48 @ffmpeg_binary="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe",  @filename="test1.mp4", @path="D:/The Vau
lt/josh ruby/video transcoding", @full_filename="D:/The Vault/josh ruby/video transcoding/test1.mp4", @raw_response=
"ffmpeg version N-51106-g17c1881 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers\n  built on Mar 19 2013 13:49:37 with
gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)\n  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bz
lib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable
-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-am
rwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspe
ex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-
libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib\n  libavutil      52. 19.101 / 52. 19.101\n
libavcodec     55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100\n  libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.      0.100\n      libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.
 0.100\n  libavfilter     3. 47.104 /  3. 47.104\n  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100\n  libswresample   0. 17
.102 /  0. 17.102\n  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100\nD:/The: No such file or directory\n", @unknown_format=t
rue>
```

Update:
Changed according to rmtsukuru's answer below but end up with. Also note that this is a different file vs above file(on different pc).

```
 irb(main):002:0> response = %x(C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i "C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/joshruby/videoTranscoding/test1.mp4")
ffmpeg version N-51205-gac9b056 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Mar 22 2013 00:04:52 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu
tls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable- libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore
-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable- librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex -
-enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc  --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxa
vs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 22.100 / 52. 22.100
libavcodec     55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
libavfilter     3. 48.100 /  3. 48.100
libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/joshruby  /videoTranscoding/test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 1
compatible_brands: isommp41avc1
creation_time   : 2009-02-19 18:49:05
 Duration: 00:00:08.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3129 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3009 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 600 tbn, 50 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2009-02-19 18:49:05
  handler_name    : ?Apple Video Media Handler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2009-02-19 18:49:05
  handler_name    : ?Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (mp4s / 0x7334706D), 0 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2009-02-19 18:49:05
  handler_name    : ?
Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (mp4s / 0x7334706D), 0 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2009-02-19 18:49:05
At least one output file must be specified
=> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg doesn't like the spaces in your input filename, and rvideo won't escape the input properly for you. If you run the command from shell manually you can get ffmpeg to run correctly, and then pass the raw response to the rvideo inspector to instantiate it correctly:

```
response = %x('#{bin_path}' -i "#{filename}")
video = RVideo::Inspector.new(:raw_response => response)
```

Replace `bin_path` with your path to the ffmpeg binary and `filename` with the path to your input file. The ffmpeg binary path doesn't have to be enclosed in quotes unless it contains spaces.

Comment: Thanks rmtsukuru, this looks more like what I expected but I still can't use video.fps, or video.resolution. When I run the response line I get a line saying "At least one output file must be specified" along with a => ""

Comment: I went ahead and tried to add an output file which worked but I'm not trying to output a file yet, just inspect.